# ¿Como puedo hacer que las secciones cambien automaticamente con javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Me podrían ayudar, necesito hacer que solo se vea un item y que cambie automaticamente, tambien manualmente si hago click en item1 y asi sucesivamente
Gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que quedara asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mas en profundidad? Para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Me gustaria que solo se mostrara el item1, y cambiara despues al item2, item3 y regresara a item1. Pero tambien que pudieras hacer click a cada item para visualizarlos}

Comment: Agregue una imagen para explicarme mejor, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo que te dejo abajo te debería servir, si lo que tu quieres tambien es ocultar las cajas desde un principio, basta con agregar dentro del `document.addEventListener` lo siguiente:

```
 for (let i=0 ; i<cajas.length ; i++) {
    cajas[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
```

Si quieres que al presionar un item, la caja suba hasta el principio en vez de solo desaparecer. Lo que tienes que hacer es en vez de aplicar:

```
cajas[i].style.opacity = 0;
```

Aplicas:

```
cajas[i].style.display = 'none';
```

Y donde antes ponias `opacity=1;` pones `display='flex';`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  
  // Guardo en un array las cajas y los items
  let cajas = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  
  for (let i=0 ; i<items.length ; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      
      // Oculto todas las cajas por si antes se habia habilitado alguna
      for (let i=0 ; i<cajas.length ; i++) {
        cajas[i].style.opacity = 0;
      }
      
      // Obtengo el id del item que se clickeó para
      // hacer visible su respectivas cajas
      let idItem = items[i].getAttribute('id');
      let numberId = idItem.charAt(idItem.length-1);
      
      cajas[numberId-1].style.opacity = 1
      
    });
  }
  
});
```

```css
.container{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bolder;
  
  box-sizing: border-box; /*El padding se hara del limite de la caja hacia adentro*/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Estilo en comun que tienen las cajas */
.container .boxes .box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  /* Centro el contenido vertical y horizontalmente */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Para darle el efecto de transición */
  transition: .2s ease 0s;
}


.box-1{
  background-color: red;
}
.box-2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.box-3{
  background-color: green;
}
.box-4{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.box-5{
  background-color: gray;
}


.item{
  cursor: pointer /* Cursor de tipo link */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <p class="item" id="item-1">Item 1</p>
    <p class="item" id="item-2">Item 2</p>
    <p class="item" id="item-3">Item 3</p>
    <p class="item" id="item-4">Item 4</p>
    <p class="item" id="item-5">Item 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box box-1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box box-2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box box-3">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box box-4">Box 4</div>
    <div class="box box-5">Box 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego!!

Comment: Podes marcar la respuesta como que resolvió tu problema por favor? :ccc

Comment: Listo! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de varias formas por javascript seria de esta forma una función que recorra el div de imágenes  oculte todas y haga aparecer la que quieres
añado la función set time para que se ejecute de forma cíclica la función 2000 implica que lo ejecutara cada dos segundos

```js
var contador=0;
function myFunction(indentifier){
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('lista').children)
  .forEach(child => {
    if(indentifier == child.id){child.style.display = "block"}else{
    child.style.display = "none"}})

}
setInterval(function(){ if(contador==document.getElementById('lista').children.length)            
  {contador=1;myFunction(contador)}
    else{contador++;myFunction(contador);/*console.log(contador)*/} }, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

img {
  width: 56px;
  height: 48px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: 26px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn success" onclick="myFunction('1')">text1</button>
<button class="btn success"  onclick="myFunction('2')">text2</button>
<button class="btn success"  onclick="myFunction('3')">text3</button>
<div id='lista'><div id='1'>
  <img src="https://playcode.io/static/img/logo.png" 
       alt="PlayCode logo" style="background-color: red;">1
</div>
<div id='2'>
  <img src="https://playcode.io/static/img/logo.png" 
       alt="PlayCode logo" style="background-color: blue;">2
</div>
<div id='3'>
  <img src="https://playcode.io/static/img/logo.png" 
       alt="PlayCode logo" style="background-color: black;">3
</div>

</div>
```

Otra opción seria solo por css te dejo otro ejemplo se utiliza el hover para desocultar la imágenes de esta forma no puedes hacerlo automático

```css
#menu {
    width:300px;
}
#menu ul {
    display:none;
}
#menu:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <img id="mb" src="//placehold.it/300x50?text=normal" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" ondragstart="return false;" onmouseover="this.src='//placehold.it/300x50/0f8000/ffffff?text=hover'" onmouseout="this.src='//placehold.it/300x50?text=normal'">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sorpresa</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <img id="mb" src="//placehold.it/300x50?text=normal" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" ondragstart="return false;" onmouseover="this.src='//placehold.it/300x50/0f8000/ffffff?text=hover'" onmouseout="this.src='//placehold.it/300x50?text=normal'">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sorpresa</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <img id="mb" src="//placehold.it/300x50?text=normal" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" ondragstart="return false;" onmouseover="this.src='//placehold.it/300x50/0f8000/ffffff?text=hover'" onmouseout="this.src='//placehold.it/300x50?text=normal'">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sorpresa</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```